# login with gmail error due to Scope querystring by google

Tags: google-plus, gmail-api, google-signin

i'm trying to implement the login with google feature on my site.

Everything was good but recently i'm facing an error

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

This error was due to a QueryString generated by google "Scope"

```
&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

If i remove the scope parameter from the url the login was a success.

Answer (score 1):

This  is because of modesecurity restrictions from your hosting provider, request them to disable modesecurity for your domain.I was facing same issue,after contacting to support center they disabled modesecurity and issue solved.